# How to create multiline refresh in unix shell

Tags: shell, unix, terminal, carriage-return

I know how to make the last line of a terminal app refresh itself by clearing `\r` carriage return at the line.

How can I do this with more lines than just the last? (how do programs like vi do it?)

EDIT
Without externals such like `ncurses`, `tput`, etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I do this with more lines than just the last? (how do programs
>   like vi do it?)

They're using `ncurses`, `termcap`, `terminfo`, the lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it without using `curses` and the like, then you'll have to know which terminal control codes to send for each different terminal type that you plan to support.

You also need to know how to achieve the required effect in terms of the operations that each terminal does support.  Some terminals may have a single 'clear to end of screen' command; others may require many characters to be written.

On the whole, it might be easier to use something designed to handle the job — and the `terminfo` terminal database.